# Converting Videos To Same Resolution Then Joining Them

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

I have a bunch of clips that I'm trying to combine into one video. The problem is each clip has a different resolution and aspect ratio (different SAR and DAR sometimes too). I'm trying to get everything to be 1920x1080 16:9 (same SAR and DAR) with a black background filling in the extra space. Here's what I currently have:

```
ffmpeg  -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=(iw*sar)*max(1920/(iw*sar)\,1080/ih):ih*max(1920/(iw*sar)\,1080/ih), crop=1920:1080,setsar=1:1" -c:v mpeg4 -vtag XVID -q:v 4 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.avi
```

This gets everything to 1920x1080, **but it crops videos that aren't 16:9.** I'd like non-16:9 videos to have extended black bars instead.

Here's what I'm using to combine all the clips after they've been resized.

```
ffmpeg -i input1.avi -i input2.avi ... input14.avi -filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] [2:v] [2:a] ... [14:v] [14:a] concat=n=15:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv
```

In it's current form it joins the videos no issues. In the past, this script has had issues when the first one converts vertical videos "properly." Usually it would complain about SAR and/or DAR being wrong.

In conclusion, how can I modify the first command to properly size any/all resolutions/aspect rations to 1920x1080 16:9 with the same SAR and DAR? Then (if needed) how would I modify the second script to combine the converted videos?

Comment: What error(s) do you get when you try joining?

Comment: Currently none. These commands work aside from the first cropping vertical video (what I'd like fixed). In the past I'd get an error about the SAR of videos not matching so they can't be joined. I got this error when the first handled vertical videos properly.

Comment: So, is it working or not working? The mention about cropping the vertical video seems a minor aside in the post, and nothing indicates it is the thing you're actually asking. Perhaps use the EDIT button and rephrase your post to make your actual question clear.

Comment: Edited to hopefully clarify.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The scale filter has some bespoke options for proportional resizing. Use the pad filter afterwards to add black bars.

`ffmpeg  -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1,setsar=1" -c:v mpeg4 -vtag XVID -q:v 4 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 4 output.avi`

(I would suggest output to MP4/MOV for these intermediate files, using their default codecs. MPEG-4 Part 2 in AVI is outdated.)

Comment: I used your command with mp4 output instead of AVI (dropped the `-vtag`). I get this error on my combine command now. `[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0x5614c40b3500] Input link in0:v0 parameters (size 1920x1080, SAR 240:239) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1920x1080, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0x5614c40b3500] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #11:0`

Comment: See edited cmd.